# trouble with xpath query in rapid miner

Tags: xpath, rapidminer

I'm having trouble using xpath in Rapidminer.  Below is a sample html that I'm trying to pull data from.  I'm having trouble getting the number 7001 and Calfornia.

I use `//h:span[@class='detail-block']//h:/text()` and I can get "Number:"
Then I try `//h:span[@class='detail-block']/span//h:/text()` and get nothing.  I tried a bunch of variation of this and still come up with nothing.  I'm able to get things to work on google spreadsheet =importXML, but not rapidminer.

```
<div class="information">
<h2 class="underline">Information</h2>
<span class="detail-block"><span class="detail-attribute">Number:&nbsp;</span>         
<span>7001</span></span>
<span class="detail-block"><span class="detail-attribute">Location:&nbsp;</span> <span>California</span></span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not see why your "working" example (`//h:span[@class='detail-block']//h:/text()`) should do. The `h:` is an namespace prefix. hand has to be followed by an node or an attribute.

`//h:span[@class='detail-block']//text()` will return any dependent text nodes  to span[@class='detail-block']: `Number: 7001 Location: California`

For "Number:" use:
   `//h:span[@class='detail-block'][1]/h:span[1]/text()`

For "7001
  `//h:span[@class='detail-block'][1]/h:span[2]//text()`

And for "California"

`//h:span[@class='detail-block'][2]/h:span[2]//text()`

Comment: @user2503901: If this was what you are looking for, please consider to  mark the answer as valid. (Perhaps look to the faq).